# InvalidValueError: initAutocomplete is not a function Google Places and Autocomplete API

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, google-places-api, geocoding, google-places

Hope you can help as I've hit a wall, I'm also quite new to using Google's Places APIs.

I'm not going to post any code just yet as my code works fine when the 2 pieces I am about to describe run in isolation.

I am using Google's Places in addition to the Autocomplete API working from the Javascript examples provided by Google.

Initially I had the following script at the bottom of my document:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

and this script at the top of my document:

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
```

This gave me the, "You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors." so after looking into this I merged both together like this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete&sensor=false"></script>
```

However, now that I have done this, I receive the following errors:

```
InvalidValueError: initAutocomplete is not a function
TypeError: searchBox is undefined
```

I don't receive these errors when theses scripts are not merged, but I realised afterwards that the functions requiring the Places API stopped working. If I remove the Autocomplete API reference, the Places functions work.

Any ideas on how I can make both of these work together, merging these as shown and solving the 'not a function' issue?

Any suggestions would be much appreciate, please let me know if you really need to see the code.

Thanks in advance,
Steph

Answer (score 24):

You should use include script just once, like:

```
//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=__API-KEY__&libraries=places
```

Note that you omit the 'callback' param when including script.
Then load initAutocomplete on window load like:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initAutocomplete);
```

Maybe you would need to include gmaps script in head or you would get 'google is not defined' error, if you placed your js inline.

Comment: Yeah this works! If you want the JavaScript in your external JS file instead of in the HTML/PHP page like the example, this works well. Drop the callback, add the dom listener in your JS. Worked like a dream! BUT don't forget the geolocate() onFocus... you would need to move that to your external JS as well...

Comment: I had the same issue using it with WordPress but I noticed that this only happens if my autocomplete function was written inside the JQuery onload function, so i moved it out. I havent tested for vanilla js's onload function but it should typically be the same approach nonetheless.

Comment: This solution works for me. In my case, I removed `async` attr from the Maps API script tag too.

Comment: this was the only thing that worked for me

Answer (score 5):

Just tried this and found that removing the `asyc` attribute solves this problem. Even when using the callback on the Google API URL for Places.

Removing the `async` attribute is a smaller fix.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `&callback=initAutocomplete` from the query and call it in the script when all will be loaded.